# Небольшие проблемы с вёрсткой

Tags: html, css, разметка

У меня такая пробла.

Есть 3 дива:

```
|           |    |           |    |           |
|   DIV1    |    |   DIV2    |    |   DIV3    |
|_ _ _ _ _ _|    |_ _ _ _ _ _|    |_ _ _ _ _ _|
```

- `DIV1` кидается влево (`float: left`),
- `DIV3` кидается вправо (`float: right`),
- `DIV2` должен быть по центру (`float: left`, так написал в стиле, и он стал по центру).

`DIV1` и `DIV3` — невидимые. Они появляются при наведении мышки на один объект `X`. Но тогда `DIV2` (когда `DIV1` и `DIV3` невидимые) перестаёт быть по центру, т. к. он получался по центру из-за того, что `DIV1` тоже имеет свойство `float: left`.

Так как его выровнять?
Т. е. при не наведении на объект `X` получим:

```
                 |           |                 
                 |   DIV2    |                 
                 |_ _ _ _ _ _|
```

А при наведении:

```
|           |    |           |    |           |
|   DIV1    |    |   DIV2    |    |   DIV3    |
|_ _ _ _ _ _|    |_ _ _ _ _ _|    |_ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Желательно без таблиц (с таблицей я знаю как, просто интересно: можно ли без неё обойтись?) и чтобы поменьше плохого кода и стиля.

Comment: весь вопрос выглядит превосходно, но "программистский жаргон" всё портит

Answer (score 2):

[[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan), скопировал Ваш код, ничего кроме DIV 2 не увидел, при наведении мышки результат=0. Посему вот мой вариант:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0px auto; }
    #wrapper .c-div { /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/height: 100px;}
    .c-div { height: 100px;}
    .c-div .container { display: none; }
    .c-div:hover .container { display: block;}
    #div1 { width: 199px;float: left; }
    #div3 { width: 199px; float: right;}
    #div2 { width: 498px;margin: 0px 200px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="c-div" id="div1">
        <div class="container">DIV 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-div" id="div3">
        <div class="container">DIV 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-div" id="div2">DIV 2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у меня чего-то DIV3 не появляется. Но идея понятна, спасибо.

Comment: т.е. Вам надо чтоб одновременно появлялся div1 и div3?

Comment: да, нужно, чтобы одновременно. 

но я уже разобрался в идее, если хотите, подправьте ответ свой для точности :)

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: hidden;` при наведении на объект `X` `visibility: visible;`.
Вместо `display: none | block`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0px auto; }
#DIV-1, #DIV-2, #DIV-3 { width: 300px; float: left; text-align: center; }
#DIV-1, #DIV-3 { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="DIV-1">DIV 1</div>
    <div id="DIV-2">DIV 2</div>
    <div id="DIV-3">DIV 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```